# wrap text around image in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

i was try to wrap text around image in pdf, i have tried lots of things but its not work in mpdf
[image: Format 1]

[image: format 2]

basically i want format of my pdf as above images

below is a code for format 1

```
<div class="content" style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="main_img" style="height:300px; width:300px; float:right;
                        margin-left: 1em;">
                        <img src="' . "./uploads/$main_images" . '" style="height:300px; width:100%; float:right; justify:end;" />
                        </div>
                        <p style="text-align: justify; word-wrap: break-word;">' . $content . '</p>
                        <p style="text-align: justify;">' . $content2 . '</p>
                        <div class="other_img" style="height:300px width:100%; margin: 5px;">
                            <div class="oth_img" style=" background-image: url(' . "./uploads/$oth_images" . '); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; height:300px; width:100%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

code for format 2

```
<div class="content" style="">
                    <div class="other_img" style="height:300px width:100%; margin: 5px;">
                        <div class="oth_img" style=" background-image: url(' . "./uploads/$oth_images" . '); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; height:300px; width:100%;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <p style="text-align: justify;">' . $content . '</p>
                    <div class="main_img" style="height:300px; width:300px; float:left; margin: 5px; margin-bottom:100px;">
                        <img src="' . "./uploads/$main_images" . '" style="height:300px; width:100%; float:left; justify:end;" />
                    </div>
                    <p style="text-align: justify;">' . $content2 . '</p>
                </div>
```

above code work in normal html format
but its not work in pdf
please guide me to make this work in pdf also

thanks

Comment: Your CSS are missing `;` somewhere, so it may be the issue. `justify:end` is not supported in mPdf (check here https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html)

Comment: @Justinas
i use semicolon in missing place, but still not work

Comment: Maybe try setting image width to be `300px` instead of `100%`?

Comment: @Justinas still not work